# How to shift audio half a hop length?

Tags: python, audio, librosa, pydub

So I have a deep neural network that generates features from audio like w2v2 (wave2vec 2). They get trained for a long time and resulting nets have some constant feature generation rate. I also happen to be able to generate Mel spectrograms, yet for them, I can set various features sample rates (like 345x80 for hop length 320 and 690x80 for 160 from the same audio record).

All I want is to shift the audio record half a hop (to be able to generate more relevant w2v2 features from 2 runs interleaved with one another without any additional training).

So how to shift audio in python ([librosa](https://librosa.org) or [pydub](http://pydub.com)) on half a `hop_length=320`?

Comment: Just use regular array slicing, i.e. `y, sr = load(...)`, then slice `y = y[hop_length//2:]` (using librosa).